# How to res.sendFile whilst res.rendering an HTML that uses the sent file in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a file server that use node.js and Express. I have the system currently set up so that each user has a file directory. I currently have it set so that the whole file system is hosted using

```
app.use(express.static(testFolder));
```

The problem with this approach is that anyone could view anyones files even if they are not logged in. I have looked and other people recommend to not host the whole file system and use res.sendFile(specific file) instead. People also recommend to use middleware to check that the user is authenticated.

My problem with this is that, say for photos, I have a photos route and EJS file set up so that for all photos, the photo that is to be viewed is rendered inside the .ejs file.

How would I res.sendFile() but then have it rendered inside a .ejs file? As just res.sendFile() only shows the photo with a white background and no customisation.

Here is the code for the route:

```
router.post("/view/photo", function(req, res){
    var path = req.body.currentPath
    var filename = req.body.fileName
    var currentUser = req.body.currentUser
   
    var files = fs.readdirSync(path)
    var images = []
    var fileExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        fileExtension = files[i].split(".")[1]
        if(fileExtension){
            if(fileExtensions.includes(fileExtension.toLowerCase())){
                images.push(files[i])
            }
        }
    }
 
    var indexOfFile = images.indexOf(filename)
    var next = indexOfFile + 1;
    var previous = indexOfFile - 1;

    if(next > images.length - 1){
        next = next - (images.length)
    }
    if(previous < 0){
        previous = previous + (images.length)
    }

    path = path.split("/")
    path = path.splice(path.indexOf(currentUser, 0), path.length)
    path = path.join("/")
    finalPath = "../" + path + "/" + filename
    
    var nextFileName = images[next]
    var prevFileName = images[previous]

    res.sendFile(req.body.currentPath + "/" + filename);

    // res.render("showPhoto.ejs", {photoPath: finalPath, filename: filename, currentPath: req.body.currentPath, next: nextFileName, prev:prevFileName });  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about replacing `express.static` with `sendFile`. That's a red herring.

If you want to allow only authenticated users to see an *anything*, then add middleware that checks to see if they are authenticated on the route that serves up whatever the *anything* is.

It doesn't matter *how* the route serves up the *anything*, only that you authenticate the user before doing do.

If the route uses `static` to serve up an image file, then add some authentication middleware before it. If the route uses `render` to generate an HTML document which includes an `<img>` that points to the previously mentioned static route, then add some authentication middleware before it. etc.

```
router.post(
    "/view/photo",
    authenticationMiddleware,
    photoPostingEndpointFunction
);

router.use(
    "/photos",
    authenticationMiddleware,
    express.static('path/to/protected/photos)
);
```

Comment: Ok I have added a middleware that runs on every route so that if someone knew the file path then they still could not access files etc. This seems to work. I just now need to specify in the middleware which user is accessing which files. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have implemented middleware to check that the user is logged in and this is working, but I am struggling to make sure that only a user can view his folder. What would I put in the app.use(express.static(filesystem)) to make sure that this works? Because I am still able to view other users files at say this route `http://192.168.1.118:8080/Matt%20Haywood/Photos/London%20March%202020/DSC_0006.JPG` where the Matt Haywood is the users folder.

Comment: @MatthewHaywood — See the last four lines of code in the answer.

Comment: But how would this work? would I have to do `router.use(
    "/photos",
    authenticationMiddleware,
    express.static('path/to/protected/photos)
);` For each user?

Comment: Also I don't see how this would restrict other users from viewing this file?

Comment: @MatthewHaywood — You do it once, which means that nobody can access any of the photos without the `authenticationMiddleware` giving it the OK. If you need to let different users access different paths, then you need to write `authenticationMiddleware` so it pays attention to the user credentials *and* the path *and* the rules that decide which photos they are allowed to see.